# How to do right packing of paintComponent in java?

Tags: java, swing

**1.** Need set 1024*768 the size of paintComponent Area.

**2.** Need set drawing orientation of line on (0, 0, 1366,1024) but not a center.

I try to change the size in getPreferredSize() method but It's doesn't help me or doing another effect. I can't do this.
I try to change the size in getPreferredSize() method but It's doesn't help me or doing another effect.
I try to change
This is code which I can't change for my needs!

This is code which I can't change for my needs!

````
package j; 
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Path2D;
import javax.swing.JColorChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Letter {

    LetterDraw letterDraw = new LetterDraw();

    public Letter() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        
        JPanel letterDrawWrapper = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        
        letterDrawWrapper.add(letterDraw);
        letterDrawWrapper.setSize(1024,760);
        frame.add(createColorChooser(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setSize(111, 111);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JColorChooser createColorChooser() {
        JColorChooser colorChooser = new JColorChooser();
        colorChooser.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                letterDraw.setColor(colorChooser.getColor());
            }
        });
        return colorChooser;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Letter();
            }
        });
    }
}

class LetterDraw extends JPanel {

    private Color color;

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
        
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
        super.paintComponent(graphics);
        
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) graphics;
            g.setColor(color);
    
         
      
        g.setRenderingHint(
                RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
        //g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(4, BasicStroke.JOIN_BEVEL, 0));
       
        g.setColor(color);
         g.drawLine(11,11,1024,1024);  
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(150, 150);
    }
}```
````

Comment: Ok.But where I should to insert this please give me example. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Need set 1024*768 the size of paintComponent Area.

You should NOT be hard coding size values. You don't know what the resolution will be.

Also, The resolution of your screen is NOT the space available for painting. The frame has a title bar and border which takes away space for custom painting.

Painting code should be dynamic based on the space available to your panel, so the painting code would use methods like `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` to determine the painting area.

> I try to change the size in getPreferredSize()

Yes that will work to give a suggestion for the preferred size. Then you just pack() the frame. Don't use setSize() on the frame.

```
//frame.setSize(111, 111);
```

That statement is overriding the size determined by the pack() method. Get rid of it.

```
g.drawLine(11,11,1024,1024);
```

Don't hard code values. The size of the panel will change as the frame is resized. For example to draw a diagonal line on the panel the code should be:

```
g.drawLine(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

Try manually resizing the frame to see how the size of the line changes.

Edit:

You didn't add your panel to the frame:

```
frame.add(letterDraw);
```

Comment: `g.drawLine(0,0,getWidth(), getHeight());`  Line ever doesn't drawing... I has Manually resized the frame). Please, Help Me Again!

Comment: sorry I missed one. How to set all frame size not manually with a `getHeigth()` etc...

Comment: I'm not understanding your last question. You don't set the frame size (which is why you need to remove the setSize(...) statement). Each component you add to the frame has a preferred size. When you `pack()` the frame the preferred size of each component will be used to determine the frames size.